# set default communication device windows 10 powershell

Tags: audio, powershell

default communication device powershell.\

is it possible to set audio device output als default communication device in powershell? i need this because i switch between my speakers and my headphones i already use AudioDeviceCmdlets in powershell to set an audio device as default output.

i already tried doing it in de registry but powershell can't change a value in that specific part (i ran powershell in administator mode)

with this i want to create a script that can see what device is turned off or on and then knows to switch to the speakers or to my headphones as output

i already have this code:

if((Get-PnpDevice -InstanceId 'INSTANCEID' | Select-Object -Property status) -eq "OK"){
Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId 'INSTANCEID' -confirm:$false
Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId 'INSTANCEID' -confirm:$false
} Else {
Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId 'INSTANCEID' -confirm:$false
}

default audio device output headphones GAME
Set-AudioDevice -ID "deviceid"

default audio device output Speakers
Set-AudioDevice -ID "deviceid"

tanks.

Comment: I think you should look into the AudioDeviceCmdlets which you can download here: https://github.com/frgnca/AudioDeviceCmdlets

Comment: What part of the registry were you trying to write to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never tried this in PowerShell, but I am using this from PowerShell:

```
nircmd.exe setdefaultsounddevice FrontHeadphones
```

where `FrontHeadphones` is the name of an audio device, you need [NirSoft's nircmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) for this.

Comment: What did you search for? [powershell set default audio device](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+set+default+audio+device&form=ANNTH1&refig=6f11cc876d3b4be898f5177086d796e7&sp=-1&pq=powershell+set+default+audio+devi&sc=1-33&qs=n&sk=&cvid=6f11cc876d3b4be898f5177086d796e7)

Comment: this will set the device as default output and i need default communication output.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below, tweak as needed.

> [Switching Audio Input and Output With PowerShell](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2008/12/switching-audio-input-and-output-with-powershell)
>
> All the control panel dialog is doing under the hood is changing a few
> registry settings. What I wanted a script that would let me change
> from one profile to another.

```
    $r = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    $regRoot = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\"
    
    
    $profiles = @{"Netbook" = @("Realtek HD Audio output",      
                                "Realtek HD Audio input");
                "Bluetooth" = @("Bluetooth Hands-free Audio", 
                                "Bluetooth Hands-free Audio") }
    
    function Write-Message ( [string]$message )
    {
        echo $message
        # Uncomment this line to show dialog outputs from -set 
        # $r = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($message)
    }
    
    function Set-Mapping ( [string]$devOut, [string]$devIn )
    {
        echo "Profile audio:`n  in  = $devIn`n  out = $devOut"
    
        $regKey = $regRoot + "\Multimedia\Sound Mapper\"
        Set-ItemProperty $regKey -name Playback -value $devOut
        Set-ItemProperty $regKey -name Record -value $devIn
    }
    
    function List-Devices
    {
        $regKey = $regRoot + "\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Volume Control\"
        echo "Sound devices:"
        ls $regKey | where { ! $_.Name.EndsWith("Options") } | 
            Foreach-Object { 
                echo ("  " + $_.Name.Substring($_.Name.LastIndexOf("\")+1)) 
            }
    }
    
    $cmd = $args[0]
    switch ($cmd)
    {
        "-profiles" 
        {
            echo "Sound profiles:"
            echo $profiles
        }
        "-devices"
        {
            List-Devices
        }
        "-set" 
        {
            $p = $args[1]
            if (!$profiles.ContainsKey($p)) {
                echo "No such profile: $p"
                echo $profiles
                exit
            }
            Set-Mapping $profiles.Get_Item($p)[0] $profiles.Get_Item($p)[1]
            Write-Message "Profile set to: $p"
        }
        default 
        { 
            Write-Message "No such option: $cmd" 
        }
    }
```

As you can see it has three options:

> -profiles – List the available sound profiles.
> -devices – List the sound devices.
> -set [profile] – Set the audio profile.